# design procedure printString

Tags: java

basically i have a question. got new work book today from college with couple of questions and one is following:

Design a procedure printString to input an integer n and a string s, and print n copies of (the value of) n on the screen, two copies per line (except, possibly, the last line).
If the user enters a negative value for n, the computer should print a complaint.

So my code is this:( also compiles and does whatever the question asked me to do)

```
import java.util.*;


public class Question5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = "";
        int n = 0;

        System.out.println("Type in any string");
        s = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Type in any integer");
        n = input.nextInt();

        if (n > 0) {
            while (n > 1) {
                System.out.println(s + "\t" + s);
                --n;
                --n;
            }
            if(n == 1){
                System.out.print(s);
                --n;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please do not use negative value.");
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to ask what did my teacher have in mind by saying procedure printString? a method?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the point of asking for `s` if you're only supposed to be printing the value of `n`?

Comment: This is probably what they meant, but really you should be asking them, not StackOverflow.

Comment: The best person in the _whole_ world to tell you what your teacher had in mind is ... your teacher.

Comment: @Andreas Must be a typo, OP's code does print `s` n times (just all in `main`).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I know, I'm hinting at OP that there's a problem in the question text, so it can be fixed.

Comment: I would say that *"Design a procedure printString to input an integer n and a string s"* in Java-speak means *"Write a method named `printString` with an integer parameter `n` and a string parameter `s`"*, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Andreas Right. I suppose the teacher could mean "follow the Rational Unified Process to create the specifications of a procedure named `printString` and depict its' arguments there-in."

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a printString function than it could be implemented as:

```
public static void printString(String s, int n)
{
    if(n<0)
    {
        System.out.println("Please do not use negative value.");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i=i+2)
        {
            System.out.println(s+" "+s);
        }
    }
}
   public static void main(String[] args) {

printString("String",6);
}
```